# Python appending to a list from a string with the same name

Tags: python

I have the following list.

```
('A', 'Steve', 'AAPLES', '0', '0', '15')
('B', 'Steve', 'ORANGES', '0', '0', '100')
('C', 'Paul', 'GRAPES', '0', '0', '500')
```

I want to loop through each line and then append the line to a list with the same name as line[0].

I am trying something like:

```
A = []
B = []
C = []

for line in test_file:
    group = line[0].strip(' ')
    group.append(line)
```

This isn't working because 'group' is an string. can I make group a non string so I can append to that list?

Comment: You need to use a dictionary here.

Comment: Can you include what you want your final result to be?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using a dictionary that map names to a lists:

```
A = []
B = []
C = []

group_dict = {'A': A, 'B': B, 'C': C}

for line in test_file:
    group = line.strip()[0]
    group_dict[group].append(line)
```

Comment: possibly want to append `line[1:]` to discard the name from the line.